# Calculate days since last program installed using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

What is the way to find all recently installed/repaired/modified software?

What I have been trying is to get the list from the registry, then filter it to find only relevant programs, and then try to calculate which of them was installed before a certain threshold.

This is what I have been doing:

```
$Installed_Software=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
$SoftwareInstall_Days = 40
$TheDate = (([datetime]::Now))

$Installed_recently= @()
$Installed_recently=($Installed_Software |
Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -match ('Something') -or $_.Publisher -match ('SomeOtherThing'))} |
where (($TheDate - $_.InstallDate) -le $SoftwareInstall_Days)

if ($Installed_recently) {
    Write-Output "Relevant software was recently installed and/or repaired / modified.`nThese are the items:`n$Installed_recently"
}
else {
    Write-Output "No relevant software was recently installed and/or repaired / modified."
}
```

Of course, the following condition is just an illustration of what I am failing to do:

```
where (($TheDate - $_.InstallDate) -le $SoftwareInstall_Days)
```

How can this be done?

Am I even in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to compare dates, you need to parse the `InstallDate` string that you get from registry and then subtract it from the current date.

There are couple of formats that this string can be. On my machine, English Win10 x86, I see 2 date formats: `yyyyMMdd` and `MM/dd/yyyy`.
In the code below, I created an array that you can add additional formats to parse.

Here is the modified code - I used "Microsoft" string to test:

```
# Add additional property InstallDateObj that will hold the parsed DateTime object
$Installed_Software=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object  DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, InstallDateObj
$SoftwareInstall_Days = 40
$TheDate = (([datetime]::Now))

# Try to parse dates.
$Installed_Software.ForEach({

    # add more formats if you need
    [string[]] $formats = @("yyyyMMdd","MM/dd/yyyy")

    $installDate = $_.InstallDate
    $installedDateObj = $null;    
    $formats.ForEach({ [DateTime] $dt = New-Object DateTime; if([datetime]::TryParseExact($installDate, $_, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$dt)) {  $installedDateObj = $dt} }); 
    $_.InstallDateObj = $installedDateObj
})

$Installed_recently= @()
$Installed_recently=($Installed_Software |
Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -match ('Microsoft') -or $_.Publisher -match ('Microsoft') -and ($_.InstallDateObj -ne $null) -and ($TheDate - $_.InstallDateObj).Days -le $SoftwareInstall_Days)})

if($Installed_recently.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Output "Relevant software was recently installed and/or repaired / modified.`nThese are the items:`n"
    Write-Output $Installed_recently
}
else {
    Write-Output "No relevant software was recently installed and/or repaired / modified."
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! The only thing I needed to add is a check that $_.InstallDateObj is not null, because it gave out a lot of errors. This is the edited line: 
Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -match ('Microsoft') -or $_.Publisher -match ('Microsoft') -and ($_.InstallDateObj -ne $null) -and (($TheDate - $_.InstallDateObj).Days -le $SoftwareInstall_Days))})

Answer (score 1):

There are methods for datetime object to add or remove minutes,hours,days,years from datetime, see script below. 
For your current exmaple of getting software from registry, InstallDate need to be converted to a datetime format and then compared to a needed date from report.

```
#Report date 40 days
$SoftwareInstall_Days = (([datetime]::Now)).AddDays(-40)
#Getting installed software and filtering based on report date
$Installed_recently=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, @{Name = "InstalledDate" ; Expression = {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) } }| where {$_.installeddate -ge $SoftwareInstall_Days}
#Output
$Installed_recently
```

Installed software also can be gathered from different places:

```
#Using WMI
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product

#Using PS Software provider
Get-Package
```

Comment: Oleksii, while this solution is less suitable for my specific objective, its simplicity is very impressive! Thank you!

Comment: I can't find installdate using get-package.

Comment: @bizna it does exactly what you need if you will add your if statement later
if ($Installed_recently)

Comment: @js2010 Get-Package is part of PackageManagement module, available on PowerShell 5.1. and higher.

Comment: Yes, I can run get-package, but I don't see it returning the installdate attribute.

Comment: @Oleksii, this code is a part of a larger implementation, and considering the needs of the implementation, the selected answer was exactly to the point.